# Why this function is not returning an integer instead returning a none type in python?

Tags: python, integer, reverse, nonetype

Here I am trying to get a reversed integer but instead I am getting a none type when I am passing a negative integer to the function. Can you identify the logic mistake I did. Here is the code that I am attaching for your reference.

```py
class Solution(object):
    def reverse(self, x):

        self.c = x
        if (x<0 ):
            a = -1 * x
        else :
            a = x
            a = str(a)
            b = a[::-1]
            
            b = int(b)
            
            if (x<0 and b<2**31-1):   # I think the problem is rising here 
                return -1*b
            elif (x>=0 and b<2**31-1):
                return -1*b
            else : 
                b = 0
                
                return b
            
s = Solution()
print((s.reverse(-1534)))
```

Comment: Your first if condition is : if (x<0 ):
            a = -1 * x and then there is no other logic happening since you are not entering the else clause.

Comment: Because not all possible code paths have a return statement.

Comment: You're indentation is wrong.  You only want the single line after the `else:` indented.  You want `a = str(a)` and the following lines to be called whether or not `x` is negative.

Answer (score 2):

In the first branch of your conditional:

> ```
> if (x<0 ):
>     a = -1 * x
> ```

You don't return anything, so in this case your function returns `None`.